# How can I create an unlimited range for cloud functions?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-sheets-api

I'm creating a cloud function to read a google spreadsheets and I want that use an unlimited range. It´s that possible?

The idea is read the Google spreadsheets and send the data to firebase.

I know that in Google spreadsheets I can use something like this "Shets1!A2:L".

My function it would be something like this:

```
exports.readsheets_Filmes = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT({
        email: serviceAccount.client_email,
        key: serviceAccount.private_key,
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
    })

    await jwtClient.authorize() // Autorização para acesso
    

    const {data} = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        auth: jwtClient,
        spreadsheetId: "",
        range: `Shets!A2:L`,
    })

    data.values?.forEach(row => {
        const [title, main_genre, genre_two] = row
        firestore.collection("Filmes").doc().set({
            title, main_genre, genre_two
        })
    })
})
```

I created this functions using typescript.

Does anyone know how to answer this problem?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (if the cloud-function throws and error add it textually)

Comment: @Rubén I posted an example of my function in my question. The idea is to get all the information from a google spreadsheet from cell A2. I don't know where the end of the spreadsheet is.

Comment: Besides the code a [mcve] includes more information like sample input data and the expected result, execution logs, and if any the textual error message.

Answer (score 0):

After a long time, I know how to answer this questions.

I made this change and it´s work.

```
const {data} = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        auth: jwtClient,
        spreadsheetId: "",
        range: `Shets!A2`,
    })
```